# How to display rich text format (rtf) using Qt Quick?

Tags: c#, qt, qml, rtf, qtquick2

I am new to Qt. I have a winform application in c# in which I display [Microsoft rich text format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format) text in a `RichTextBox`. RichTextBox is an control that you can write rich text like bold italic color text and insert image and ...

Now I want to write my application with **qt quick** but I don't know how to display it and in which controls?  If this is not possible, what is the replacement of rtf in Qt? (For example html or ... ?) So I can convert rtf to html and bind html to that control to display it.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what `RichTextBox` offers, but there are two options: [`TextField`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-textfield.html), which offers you an input box where users can enter text, and [`Text`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-text.html#details), which simply displays text including multiple lines and `HTML` support.

One code example can be seen here:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

// Filename.qml
Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480

    TextField {
        placeholderText: "I am a TextFiel"
    }

    Text {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: "And I am a Text"
    }
}
```

This code snipplet creates a new `Window` with a `TextField`in the top left and a `Text`-item in the center. You can open this in QtCreator and go to the Designer-Tab to view it.

Alternatively, you can run this code with a tool called `qmlscene` provided by Qt itself. If you have installed Qt on your (Windows) machine and set your `PATH` environment variable to e.g. "C:\Qt\5.7\msvc2013\bin" (on Windows), then you can even run this in command line. So you can press `Alt`+ `Shift` + Right-Click (somewhere in space next to the file), select "Open command window here" and type:

> qmlscene Filename.qml

Answer (score 1):

As derM pointed out, there is no support for Microsoft *.rtf format in QML, but for cases, when you have plain rich text, you could use solution from QML reference:

```
TextEdit {
  width: 240
  text: "<b>Hello</b> <i>World!</i>"
  font.family: "Helvetica"
  font.pointSize: 20
  color: "blue"
  focus: true
}
```

And if you want just to display rich text:

```
Text {
  text: "My <b>rich</b> text"
  textFormat: Text.RichText
}
```

Comment: Though this is called `RichText` I doubt, that it will satisfy the OP, as he asks to output the [`Microsoft Rich Text Format`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format) which has another markup. Still +1 for your answer as it should help the OP, to write a translator from RTF to HTML. You might append to your answer, that there is no RTF-Support implemented in QML.

Answer (score -2):

Use the QTextedit widget. It supports html too.

```
QTextEdit* te = new QTextEdit(this);
te->setAcceptRichText(true);
te->setText(myText);
```

Comment: This is QtWidget, but OP was asking about qtquick, which means QML.

Comment: But I want in qt quick note widget.